# Understanding graphs in TF 2.0 beta

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm doing experiments with NN. Everything is perfect when I don't put @tf.function decorator on my train_one_step function. When I say perfect, I mean everything works as expected. However, training is terribly slow, so I have to put the decorator back on. As I do this, weird things start to happen and I don't understand it and therefore cannot do any experiments. For example, after dome training, I decided to go and delete the optimizer,

```
del optimizer
```

Then do some more training, and .... nothing is wrong and training goes as usual !! what the heck? I deleted the optimizer! when I'm not putting the decorator and I delete the optimizer, the program shouts at me and says this thing is not defined (because it is required in training function). That's just one extreme example of weird things that I don't understand when the decorator is on.

My question is: can someone explain the what the decorator is doing? it seems to be taking my stuff and build a graph out of it, when its first called, but I don't have access to that graph, it sounds like things are happening in a different world where I have no control over what's happening. If I change things later in my world, they don't reflect in that world.

EDIT: Some one said that's too general and I want a code. I made a simple version based on mnist to illustrate

```
def prepare_mnist_features_and_labels(x, y):
  x = tf.cast(x, tf.float32) / 255.0
  y = tf.cast(y, tf.int64)
  return x, y

def mnist_dataset():
  (x, y), _ = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
  ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x, y))
  ds = ds.map(prepare_mnist_features_and_labels)
  ds = ds.take(20000).shuffle(20000).batch(100)
  return ds

train_dataset = mnist_dataset()

model = tf.keras.Sequential((
    tf.keras.layers.Reshape(target_shape=(28 * 28,), input_shape=(28, 28)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)))
model.build()
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()

compute_loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)

compute_accuracy = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()


@tf.function
def train_one_step(model, x, y):
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    logits = model(x)
    loss = compute_loss(y, logits)

  grads = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
  optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))

  compute_accuracy(y, logits)
  return loss


def train(model):
  train_ds = mnist_dataset()
  step = 0
  loss = 0.0
  accuracy = 0.0
  for x, y in train_ds:
    step += 1
    loss = train_one_step(model, x, y)
    if tf.equal(step % 10, 0):
      tf.print('Step', step, ': loss', loss, '; accuracy', compute_accuracy.result())
  return step, loss, accuracy

step, loss, accuracy = train(model)
print('Final step', step, ': loss', loss, '; accuracy', compute_accuracy.result())
```

Now, everything is perfect. After running the code above, go to a different cell (I'm assuming Jupyter notebook). delete the optimizer, run train(model), and it works perfectly !! With no optimizer!! If the decorator wasn't on, this wouldn't have happened. This is just one extreme example of how things that I do are not reflected in whatever is happening behind the scenes.

To be extra clear, this is from TF website tutorial, but I made some changes, including removing the parameter 'optimizer' that was being passed from train function to train_one_step cause I thought it is global and you don't need to keep passing it around.

Comment: can you please provide us with the full code? it is very difficult to answer such a general question because many things could cause this

Comment: @Kenivia I went ahead and made a simplistic version of the problem for you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

so I think what you've done by doing this:

```
del optimizer
```

is that you deleted the variable that you used to build the graph. By the time you did that, you have already constructed the graph which means that deleting the variable won't do anything.

If you want to change the optimizer, you can recompile it by:

```
model.compile(optimizer='Adam')
```

btw, I think you are overcomplicating things. why don't you use the fit function provided by keras?

btw2, I just thought about it and I'm pretty sure a model can run perfectly without optimizers, I'll try that later or you can try it yourself

-- edit: you cant, i tried

hope it helps some what :)

Comment: At what line exactly did the graph get built?